# How to use AWS ECR image in AWS codebuild?

Tags: aws-codebuild, amazon-ecr, sqitch

I am learning CICD with AWS codebuild. I use [sqitch](https://sqitch.org/) to manage database changes in my project. I have successfully configured [docker-sqitch](https://github.com/sqitchers/docker-sqitch) for the Snowflake database and it is working fine in the Ubuntu system. Now, I am trying to automate this thing so I have created an AWS ECR image for Snowflake and pushed it on AWS. It was successfully built and push it on ECR. But I don't know how to use it that ECR image with codebuild to manage my database change.

Here is my buildspec file:

```
version: 0.2
   

    phases:
      
      pre_build:
        commands:
        
           - export SQITCH_IMAGE=ccount_id.amazonaws.com/docker-snowflake-sqitch:latest
        
           - echo Logging in to Amazon ECR...
           
           - REPOSITORY_URI=account_id.amazonaws.com/docker-snowflake-sqitch
           - echo Repository url is  $REPOSITORY_URI
         
         
      build:
        commands:
          - echo Build started on `date`
          - echo Building the Docker image...
         # - echo Repository url is  $REPOSITORY_URI
          - docker run -d $REPOSITORY_URI:latest
          - docker ps
    
      post_build:
        commands:
          - echo Build completed on `date`
          - sqitch verify
```

I am getting an error while using sqitch command. So, can you please guide me on how to use ECR image with codebuild?